# Getting exception stack running Vaadin Hilla example

Tags: java, vaadin, hilla

I wanted to give a try to Vaadin Hilla project.

1. Downloaded Vaadin Hilla Example from https://github.com/vaadin/hilla-examples
2. Imported as Maven project into Eclipse STS
3. run mvnw in the terminal
4. Few minutes later got white screen which error stack:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end -1, length 125
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:4604) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:2707) ~[na:na]
    at dev.hilla.engine.commandrunner.CommandRunner.lambda$getCurrentJavaProcessJavaHome$2(CommandRunner.java:208) ~[engine-core-2.3.2.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[na:na]
    at dev.hilla.engine.commandrunner.CommandRunner.getCurrentJavaProcessJavaHome(CommandRunner.java:206) ~[engine-core-2.3.2.jar:na]
    at dev.hilla.engine.commandrunner.CommandRunner.environment(CommandRunner.java:226) ~[engine-core-2.3.2.jar:na]
    at dev.hilla.engine.commandrunner.CommandRunner.createProcessBuilder(CommandRunner.java:174) ~[engine-core-2.3.2.jar:na]
    at dev.hilla.engine.commandrunner.CommandRunner.executeCommand(CommandRunner.java:118) ~[engine-core-2.3.2.jar:na]
    at dev.hilla.engine.commandrunner.CommandRunner.executeWithTestArguments(CommandRunner.java:85) ~[engine-core-2.3.2.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList$RandomAccessSpliterator.tryAdvance(AbstractList.java:706) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:129) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:527) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513) ~[na:na]
```

It is using Spring Boot 3.1.5 and Hilla 2.3.2 with Java 17.

Anyone had similar problem?
Please advise where to dig.

Thank you.

I have tried to bump-up to 3.1.6 and Hilla 2.4.0 without luck. Same error.

Comment: Seems similar to this issue (https://github.com/vaadin/hilla/issues/1704), which should be fixed in Hilla 2.3.4.